# Multi Nested Trees with Elasicsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

i have some products and categories in a MySQL-DB.

Each product is listed in n-categories.
All categories are listed in a Tree, so each category has a parentCat until the first level.

Now i am searching for the best elastic-index-structure to query my products and filter them by categories and sub-categories.

I am searching since some days in the web, but cant find a good solution. Perhaps somebody here can help me or give a hint.

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest an document aggregated, elasticsearch is a NoSql documented oriented.
You can have an structure like this:

```
curl -XPOST "http://192.168.99.100:9200/shop/products" -d'
{
   "name": "White shoes",
   "sizes": [
      40,
      41,
      42
   ],
   "info": "bla bla bla",
   "categories": [
      {
         "name": "Social Shoes",
         "parentCat": {
            "name": "Social"
         }
      },
      {
         "name": "Winter Shoes",
         "parentCat": {
            "name": "Winter 2016"
         }
      }
   ]
}'
```

Example query with consume this structure, let's supose that i need a product that have relations with parent category called Social, category called Social Shoes

```
curl -XPOST "http://192.168.99.100:9200/shop/products/_search" -d'
{
    "query": {
       "nested": {
          "path": "categories",
          "query": {
              "bool": {
                  "must": [
                     {
                         "match": {
                            "categories.id": 1
                         }
                     },
                     {
                         "nested": {
                            "path": "categories.parentCat",
                            "query": {
                                "bool": {
                                    "must": [
                                       {
                                           "match": {
                                              "categories.parentCat.id": 1
                                           }
                                       }
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                         }
                     }
                  ]
              }
          }
       }
    }
}'
```